# How to create bar chart with multi level labels?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-core, bar-chart

[image]

How to create bar chart like that with .net core, can I create it with html javascript or kendo ui?

I use kendo ui but it doesn't support this chart type,I use .net core
Pls help me!!!!

```
@(Html.Kendo().Chart<Commsights.Data.DataTransferObject.DashbroadDataTransfer>()
    .Name("ChartTopProductByBrand")
    .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "min-height:400px;" })
    .Title(t => t.Text("Top Product by Brand").Color("#0000ff").Font("20px sans-serif"))
    .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
    .Read(read => read.Action("sp_loadTopProduct_byBrandTolist", "Dashbroad").Data("FilterCompany"))
    )
    .Legend(legend => legend.Position(ChartLegendPosition.Bottom))
    .ChartArea(chartArea => chartArea.Background("#ffffff"))
    .Events(events => events.SeriesClick("onSeriesClick"))
    .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "width: 100%; height: 400px;" })
    .Theme("material")
    .SeriesColors("#1a8cdc", "#f9a83a", "#cc3e3e", "#00a36a", "#7f58af", "#e54d42", "#2f83c3", "#f3bd42"
    , "#bf3e8f", "#60bd68", "#e44b23", "#6d9cbb", "#e6a9b8", "#76923c", "#ac4f47", "#4c6d8f", "#d1a154", "#9074a5"
    , "#c5b62c", "#5c5c5c", "#8fb0d9", "#c69c6d", "#69a8c3", "#e7d26f", "#bca7a7", "#77bc43", "#ab9d95", "#b6d957", "#dd6262", "#e0a646")
    .SeriesDefaults(seriesDefaults => seriesDefaults.Bar().Stack(true))
    .Series(series =>
    {
        series.Bar(model => model.ProductName_ProjectNameCount)
        .Name("Product")
        .Opacity(0.7)
        .CategoryField("CompanyName_Product")
        .Tooltip(tooltip => tooltip.Visible(true).Template("#= kendo.toString(category) # - #= value # article")).Color("#0033FF");
    })
    .ValueAxis(axis => axis.Numeric())
    .Tooltip(tooltip => tooltip.Visible(true).Format("{0:N0}"))
    .Pannable(pannable => pannable.Lock(ChartAxisLock.Y))
    )
```

Comment: You should perhaps read [ask].

Comment: https://docs.telerik.com/aspnet-core/html-helpers/charts/bar-chart/stacked-bar

Comment: This is more a Kendo UI or JS question, I recommend adding those tags.

Comment: sorry i not good english, I mean how to create multi levels label like a first pic